# Address box in a form

Tags: forms, input, text

My users will need to fill the address line and be very precise since the address represents their client's location (including apartment number, floor, etc.).

However, I would like to use only 1 input field instead of several.

**I wonder, is there a search engine that can receive a messy input with apt. number, floor, etc and yield an accurate address to show up on Google Maps in the right text order?**

Comment: Probably an autocomplete (getting address data from some API) field is the best solution because the user will start to type his address and then your page will suggested a ready address. Them they just need to select the right one.

Comment: the one missing piece is the ability to enter an apartment number, of floor.. I was hoping to find an engine that can understand from the user input what parts are the street and city address and what parts are the floor and apartment, and yield a readable input so the user could confirm.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Autocomplete for Addresses and Search Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) provides this feature.

***EDITED:**
[View Example on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/A1taiR/tqd9u280/) or [View Example on Developer.Google](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }

      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }

      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }

      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
      <div>
        <div id="title">
          Autocomplete search
        </div>
        <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
          <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
          <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
          <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
          <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
        </div>
        <div id="strict-bounds-selector" class="pac-controls">
          <input type="checkbox" id="use-strict-bounds" value="">
          <label for="use-strict-bounds">Strict Bounds</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="pac-container">
        <input id="pac-input" type="text"
            placeholder="Enter a location">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="infowindow-content">
      <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
      <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
      <span id="place-address"></span>
    </div>

    <script>
      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13
        });
        var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
        var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
        // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
        // bounds option in the request.
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
        autocomplete.setFields(
            ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          marker.setVisible(false);
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
            // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
          }

          // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
          }
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setVisible(true);

          var address = '';
          if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
          }

          infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
          infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
          infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
        // Autocomplete.
        function setupClickListener(id, types) {
          var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
          radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            autocomplete.setTypes(types);
          });
        }

        setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
        setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
        setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
        setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);

        document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
            .addEventListener('click', function() {
              console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
              autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: this.checked});
            });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you copy and paste the relevant portions into your answer?

Comment: Thanks! as I wrote in another comment: 
the one missing piece is the ability to enter an apartment number, of floor.. I was hoping to find an engine that can understand from the user input what parts are the street and city address and what parts are the floor and apartment, and yield a readable input so the user could confirm.